# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spacy.language'

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pycharm, spacy

In PyCharm I run a Python script that contains the line

```
from spacy.language import Language
```

Even though Spacy 3.7.2 is installed, I get the error message

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spacy.language'
```

When I run the same file on the MacOS X Terminal, with the same Python 3.11 interpreter it runs smoothly.

I inserted the line

```
import spacy
```

before the "from spacy.language import Language" line, and PyCharm did not complain. So for some reason it sees spacy, but not spacy.language…

Here is some more information: as you can see in the screen capture on the bottom right one can see the interpreter Python 3.11, for which I have loaded spacy. But when I aks for the interpreter actually used by the notebook I get a different one (the Python 3.8.3 from miniconda). Why does the notebook use 3.8.3 when I have asked for 3.11?

[image]

Comment: When you execute the configuration in PyCharm, what is the full output in the IDE's terminal? One of the first lines of output should show you what the full command that PyCharm is running. That command may have changes to your PYTHONPATH that are affecting its ability to locate packages.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. What do you mean by "executing the configuration"?

Comment: In PyCharm you have a thing called "run confugrations". Those are the profiles that you create to run things in the IDE. I'm assuming that you created a run configuration specifically for running your Python script and are executing it by using the run button in your toolbar.

Comment: No, it is a Python notebook as follows: %load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2 and from spacy.language import Language on the next line. I use it as a notebook by clicking inside the field and then clicking on the green triange in the toolbar

Comment: try running your script directly, not using a notebook. Open your script in PyCharm, find the entry point (perhaps in a `if __name__ == '__main__':` section at the bottom of the file), and use the 'run' icon on the left gutter. If you don't see one, try right clicking the file and choosing run from the context menu.

Comment: I did as you said and it runs smoothly: Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: In other words: when ran separately the script is OK, when the same line of code appears in the NoteBook, it fails. How is this possible?